# Get elements that are not a certain type using JSoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

My DOM:

```html
<div class="testClass">
    <a><span>some text</span> but this is the only text i want to select</a> </div>
```

I want to get the "but this is the only text i want to select" without also selecting "some text". After looking through other stackoverflow posts, and reading docs, I still cannot find a way to accomplish this.

The following code prints both of the above strings, I:E "some text but this is the only text i want to select".

```java
Elements results = doc.getElementsByClass("testClass").select("a:not(a>span)");

for (Element element : results) { System.out.println(element.text()); }
```

Comment: I fixed this temporarily using
`results.select("span").remove();`

Although, there must be a cleaner way to do this